# Problem loading async data into a form and then submitting it

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, async-await

I have a component called redirectComponent in my application that simply get called and instantiated from other components of the application by calling the route where it's placed (http://localhost:4200/redirect/).

Once redirectComponent get called it makes 2 calls to the API to load some data binded to a form in the template, once the data is loaded i access the form via ViewChild and i submit it (POST method), then the job of this component it's done and i navigate back to root url: unfortunately even if the data from the API it's resolved, the binded data of the form doesn't get updated and it's submitted with undefined values.

TYPESCRIPT snippet:

```
export class RedirectComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  userName: string;
  sessionToken: string;
  sessionDuration: string;
  loggedUserNavigationUrl: string = 'someUrl.com';

  @ViewChild('microgameform')
  microgameForm: ElementRef;

  constructor(private thirdPartyGameService: ThirdPartyGameService) { }

  async ngAfterViewInit(): Promise<void> {
    await this.redirectUserToThirdPartyGame();
  }

  async redirectToThirdParty(): Promise<void> {
    this.sessionDuration = '51';

    const gameToken: GameToken = await this.thirdPartyGameService.getGameToken();
    this.sessionToken = gameToken.Token;

    const nickNameResponse: NickName = await this.thirdPartyGameService.getNickname();
    this.userName = nickNameResponse.NickName;

    this.microgameForm.nativeElement.submit();
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
  }
}
```

HTML snippet:

```
<form #microgameform name="MicrogameForm" [action]="loggedUserNavigationUrl" method="POST" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="Username" [value]="userName"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="SessionToken" [value]="sessionToken"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="SessionDuration" [value]="sessionDuration"/>
</form>
```

now when i used console.log() to see every variable just before `this.microgameForm.nativeElement.submit();` i found out that all variable were loaded but not binded to the form, this is the result i got:

[variables and form values before submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7pED.png)

i think i'm missing out something, i need to retrieve data from the API and then submit it to the form with post method.. probably i'm running into some race-condition problem but i can't figure out, i've tried call the redirect from different lifecycle hooks (eg: ngAfterViewInit) but i get different errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was related to some concurrency under the hood between these lines:

this.microgameForm.nativeElement.submit();
this.router.navigateByUrl('/');

the navigateByUrl, for some unknown reason, removes the values from the form or even worse remove the form from the html document, so the solution was to add html form to the document from the typescript code and submit the form from there.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you need to use `.subscribe()` for your asynchrone calls :

```
this.thirdPartyGameService.getNickname().subscribe( data => {
    this.sessionToken = data.Token;
});
```

if you try to log this.sessionToken outside of your subscribe it would be undefined :

```
this.thirdPartyGameService.getNickname().subscribe( data => {
    this.sessionToken = data.Token;
    // Operations with the Token
});
// this.sessionToken not loaded yet => undefined
```

Comment: problem is that: "Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<GameToken>". 

i think it's because my API method returns a Promise<GameToken> not an Observable<GameToken> so i can't subscribe!

Comment: Oh so maybe you should be using `.then()` like you would do in js (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise)